# Delete rows with zeroes in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to delete rows were on of the column values is equal to zero. What I already tried:

Method 1:

```
df = pd.read_csv('Test.txt', sep="\t", skiprows=10, header=None, 
                 names=["Gewicht", "Temperaturlinks", 
                 "Temperaturrechts",'Raumtemperatur'])
df = df[df['Gewicht'] != 0]
df
```

Method 2:

```
# Get names of indexes for which column Stock has value No
indexNames = IgnoriereAnfangswerte[IgnoriereAnfangswerte["Gewicht"] == 0].index
# Delete these row indexes from dataFrame
IgnoriereNull = IgnoriereAnfangswerte.drop(indexNamesL,inplace=True)
print(IgnoriereNull)
```

Method 3:

```
IgnoriereAnfangswerte == 0
TabelleNull = IgnoriereAnfangswerte[~(IgnoriereAnfangswerte == 0).any(axis=1)]
TabelleNull
```

My Dataframe looks like this:

```
    Gewicht     a           b           c  
0   24,534000   217,140000  219,970000  27,300000 
1   0,000000    217,350000  220,110000  27,300000
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Since we do not have your Test.txt file, could you please create a small version of it using Python code? This small, reproducible test case would be very helpful to us in solving your problem.

Comment: Iadded a part of the dataframe in the comment above. I already tried a lot, but nothing really works.

Answer (score 0):

your method 1 looks OK.
also try:

```
df = df.drop(df[df['Gewicht']==0].index)
```

Answer (score 0):

A part of your problem is that it seems that you have pairs of numbers in each column. In Python, these are `tuples`.

Here is a way to create the dataframe in Python:

```
import pandas as pd
rows = [[(24,534000), (217,140000), (219,970000), (27,300000)], 
        [(0,0), (217,350000), (220,110000), (27,300000)]]

df =pd.DataFrame(data=rows, columns=["Gewicht", "Temperaturlinks", "Temperaturrechts",'Raumtemperatur'])
```

This prints out:

```
        Gewicht Temperaturlinks Temperaturrechts Raumtemperatur
0  (24, 534000)   (217, 140000)    (219, 970000)   (27, 300000)
1        (0, 0)   (217, 350000)    (220, 110000)   (27, 300000)
```

In Pandas, you `drop` a row meeting a certain criterion. Here is how you can drop a row with a `Gewicht` of `(0, 0)`:

```
df[df['Gewicht'] != (0,0) ]
```

This will print out:

```
        Gewicht Temperaturlinks Temperaturrechts Raumtemperatur
0  (24, 534000)   (217, 140000)    (219, 970000)   (27, 300000)
```